# Datatables - filter data from AJAX source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a datatable and am fetching the data from an api. Now i have the status like active,inactive if the flag is active then i need to show in the datatble else i should not show the expired one.Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya001/qLpdems2/3/). In this fiddle am showing the active and inactive both. but i want to show only the active status.

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Subject</th>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th>Message</th>
           <th>Details</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
 </table>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing" : true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/12uwp2",
            dataSrc : ''
        },
        "columns" : [ {
            "data" : "name"
        }, {
            "data" : "email"
        }, {
            "data" : "subject"
        }, {
            "data" : "status"
        },{
            "data" : "message"
        },
        {
                "mData": "Details",
                "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                    return "<a class='delete' data-id=" + row.id + " href='/Details/" + row.id + "'>Delete</a>";
                }
        }]
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        alert("Delete button clicked for Row number " + $(this).data("id"))
    })
});
```

How to do this. Can  anyone help me how to do.

Comment: Do you want to apply client-side filtering in Javascript? The JSON API does not support queries with a filter?

Comment: how to apply the client side filtering .I want to show only the active status how to do

Comment: You need a full match for your filter, use this - `search("^" + this.value + "$", true, false, true)`; refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609577/jquery-datatables-filter-column-by-exact-match)

Comment: @Tushar Walzade but here am using api to get data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use case is: Manipulate the data returned from the server

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ajax" : {
        "url" : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/12uwp2",
        "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
            return json.filter(function(item){
                return item.status=="active";         
                });
         }
    }
});
```

The key is to use `dataSrc` properly for data manipulation.

> As a function - As a function it takes a single parameter, the JSON
>   returned from the server, which can be manipulated as required. The
>   returned value from the function is what will be used by DataTables as
>   the data source for the table.

I recommend to remove the `processing` property from DataTable initialization object since there is no heavy processing step anymore.

Docs

- [Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source - Examples](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#Examples)
- [Live Example - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbh6v209/1/)
- [Clean code example using a separate filter function - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbh6v209/2/)