# How to redraw a Datatable that uses server side processing using only the existing data in the datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, server-side

I'm trying to delete a row from a Datatable that uses server side processing (removing the row data and the row/tr visually) based on the value of certain attribute of the row.

I'm using the `remove()` function to do it and it removes the row data, but visually the table stills the same.

So I added the `draw()` function but it reinitializes the table, including the data.

So, how can I "redraw" the table after removing a row from the Datatable that uses server side processing? Is there any other function like `draw()` to redraw the table but using only the existing data in the datatable?

```
 $("#tableSelector").DataTable()
     .rows( function ( idx, data, node ) {
         return data.attribute_value == value_to_delete;
     } )
     .remove()
     .draw();
```

Comment: You've done as it says here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().remove()  must be something to do with it being server-side data

Comment: Yes, I've done some research but couldn't find any function like that. Finally I used an alternative way to solve my problem but this got me quite curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.
I followed [this thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/59238/adding-a-new-row-to-server-side-datatable-without-ajax-call) then read about the DataTable's property ["dataSrc"](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc).
Then with this information searched for something similar in Stack Overflow and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000320/datatables-filter-data-from-ajax-source).
So the trick to do what I asked for was to use a variable to filter the row which I want to ignore in the ajax call.

I've reused the code provided in the [referred question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000320/datatables-filter-data-from-ajax-source). And this is the result:

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Subject</th>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th>Message</th>
           <th>Details</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
 </table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function loadDataTable(excluded_name = undefined){
        $("#example").DataTable().destroy();
      $('#example').DataTable({
         // "processing" : true,
          "ajax" : {
              "url" : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/12uwp2",
               "dataSrc": (json) => {
               if(excluded_name !== undefined){
                return json.filter((item) => item.name !== excluded_name)
               }else{
                return json
               }
              }
          },
          "columns" : [ {
              "data" : "name"
          }, {
              "data" : "email"
          }, {
              "data" : "subject"
          }, {
              "data" : "status"
          },{
              "data" : "message"
          },
          {
             "mData": "Details",
             "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                      return "<a class='delete' data-name='"+ row.name + "' data-id=" + row.id + " href='/Details/" + row.id + "'>Delete</a>";
                  }
          }]
      });
    }
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let excluded_name = $(this).data("name")
        alert("Excluding this name in the next load: " + excluded_name);
        loadDataTable(excluded_name);
    })
    loadDataTable();
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ek94mh1x/4/

Note: This is a client side "delete", I know this could be done with server side processing, but in my case I was only allowed to do it in the client side.
Additionally, in case you need to delete multiple rows you could use an array as a parameter and follow the same logic.

I hope this could help someone.